# Android gridView loading images using adapter and Glide

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-adapter, android-glide

I'm using a GridView to show 20 images. I'm fetching and showing the images from the web using Glide in an adapter that I create. The problem is that, also if all the images are downloaded,  when I'm scrolling the grid view I'm seeing the images appearing with a fade like animation. I dont' want this. I want to have all images loaded in the gridview without seeing them appear if I scroll faster.

I've tried using diskcache() and dontAnimate() but it didnt solved my problem. I think the problem is that i'm showing 4 cells of the gridview. When i Scroll the adapter calls the getView to show other two cells and remove the 2 that I'm scrolling up. The problem is that the getview every times takes time to show other two cell and i have the effect that looks like a loading. I want my scenario to looks like a grid view with all 20 cells existing and allocated.

This is my adapter:

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Picture> images;

    public ImagesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Picture> inputImages) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.images = inputImages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Picture getItem(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            holder.id = images.get(position).getImageId();
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            holder.id = images.get(position).getImageId();
        }

        Picture pic = images.get(position);
        Glide
                .with(mContext)
                .load(pic.getBigImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        return row;
    }
     public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        public String id;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me finding solution?

Comment: Glide will attempt to download your images when they are about to appear on the screen. So there will be a delay until they show up in your cell. If you don't want any delay you have to download those images beforehand. If Glide offers cache options your images will appear immediately for the second time, but you will always have to wait for them to download first time around.

Comment: Yes, Glide is downloading them first time. But my problem is not for the first time. The second time and on i verified that images are all download, and even if are all downloaded, on the scroll they appears not immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 Glide
 .with(mContext)
 .load(pic.getBigImageUrl())
 .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultImage)
 .into(holder.imageView);
```

to knoow more abour Glide click [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a disk cache strategy to load images from cache.
you can use SOURCE or RESULT;
SOURCE Saves just the original data to cache and RESULT Saves the media item after all transformations to cache.
for example :

```
    Glide
 .with(mContext)
 .load(pic.getBigImageUrl())
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
 .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: I cant use .diskCacheStrategy in the adapter :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of caching mechanism like this example:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(pic.getBigImageUrl())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .dontAnimate().into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: I cant see .diskCacheStrategy and .dontAnimate() in the adapter :(

Comment: did you have this version of glide in gradle?

Comment: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: I have 4.0.0 now i will try 3.7.0

Comment: I've tried but it didnt solved my problem. I think the problem is that i'm showing 4 cells of the gridview. When i Scroll the adapter calls the getView to show other two cells and remove the 2 that I'm scrolling up. The problem is that the getview every times takes time to show other two cell and i have the effect that looks like a loading. I want my scenario to looks like a grid view with all 20 cells existing and allocated.

Answer (score 0):

try adding placeholder that may solve your problem

```
Glide
     .with(mContext)
     .load(pic.getBigImageUrl())
     .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultImage)
     .into(holder.imageView);
```